Can't set cookie with Fastify
Can't set cookies on Next client with Fastify backend.
I have a Next.JS client and a Fastify backend. I made this simple endpoint that sets an httpOnly cookie
server.get("/set-cookie", async (req, reply) => {
  reply.setCookie("test-cookie", "this is a test", {
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: "lax",
    domain: "localhost",
  });
  reply.send({ message: "cookie set succesfuly" });
});

This works fine on Postman, but doesn't work on my client.
This is my Nextjs component that tests the endpoint:
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
async function getCookie() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/set-cookie", {
    credentials: "include",
  });
  if (res.ok) console.log(cookies().getAll());
}
export default async function Page() {
  await getCookie();
  return <>test</>;
}


I also don't have any Set-Cookie headers in my Network tab.
